# missing subscript c++

Tags: c++, subscript

right now c++ is giving me this error: error C2087 'color' missing subscript first time i get this and i dont know what to do >.< hope any1 can help me

```
struct Color{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
Color color[][];
```

and im using it here

```
for(int i=0;i<cubes;i++)
{
    color[i][0].r = fRand();color[i][0].g=fRand(.5);color[i][0].b=fRand();
```

...etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the size of your array:

```
Color color[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to create an array without specifying its size. If the size is dynamic, you should use pointers instead. `type x[][];` is always an error, regardless of type. You can initialize your array though,
`int x[] = {10,11}; // ok` or `int[][2]={{1,2},{1,2},{1,3}}; // also works`

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of color lacks sizes for the subscripts. Therefore, the compiler cannot determine how much space to allocate for color.

Answer (score 2):

you're not specifying the size for the two-dimensional array as it seems. maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: so i should put Color color[3][3] or something above those lines?