# missing subscript error when using class template functions in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates

## Problem

I am getting a `C2087 'm': missing subscript` compile error and two `C4200 nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union` warnings when I try to calculate the determinant of a Matrix recursively.

I have a Matrix class that stores the data of the matrix in a 2D array `m` where the size is given from template parameters `int rows` and `int columns`.

**Note**: I have looked into another post about [missing subscript c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946442/missing-subscript-c) but it does not exactly answer my question since my 2D array has it's size defined by the template parameters and is not left empty.

## Code

Here is my MRE that produces the error, built in Visual Studio 2019:

**Matrix.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T, int rows, int columns>
struct Matrix
{
private:
    const int size = rows * columns;
    union
    {
        T m[rows][columns];
        T a[rows * columns];
    };

public:
    Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            a[i] = T(0);
    }

    Matrix(T* a_)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            a[i] = a_[i];
    }

    T& operator[](int index)
    {
        return a[index];
    }

    Matrix<T, rows - 1, columns - 1> LaplaceMatrix(int row, int column)
    {
        Matrix<T, rows - 1, columns - 1> res;

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            if (i == row)
                continue;

            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            {
                if (j == column)
                    continue;

                res[index] = m[i][j];
                ++index;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    T Determinant()
    {
        assert(rows == columns);

        if (rows == 2)
            return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];

        T determinant = T(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            if (m[0][i] != 0)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Matrix<T, rows - 1, columns - 1> laplace = LaplaceMatrix(0, i);
                    T det = laplace.Determinant();
                    determinant += (m[0][i] * det);
                }
                else
                {
                    Matrix<T, rows - 1, columns - 1> laplace = LaplaceMatrix(0, i);
                    T det = laplace.Determinant();
                    determinant -= (m[0][i] * det);
                }
            }
        }

        return determinant;
    }
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m(a);
    
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> laplace = m.LaplaceMatrix(0, 0);
    std::cout << laplace.Determinant() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you call `LaplaceMatrix` on a 1x1 matrix?

Comment: Also, be aware that this approach of computing determinant is extremely inefficient. [Better algorithms exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation)

Comment: "store the data of this matrix in a union" This combines all the advantages of undefined behaviour with all the advantages of extra code complexity.

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the exact text of the error you mentioned.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to specialize the base case (2x2)? (Also, you should make sizes less than 2 invalid, as well as non-square matrices.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when I call `LaplaceMatrix` on a 1x1 matrix I get the same error. Also thank you for the reference link, I will look into it for improvements.

Comment: @JaMiT I have rewritten the question after reviewing the details in the link you referenced, along with an MRE that produces the error.

Comment: @Bob__ I have rewritten the question and included an MRE as requested.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have an if statement for the 2x2 case and an assert to ensure that the matrix is a square matrix in my `Determinant` function

Comment: Thanks. Have you already studied [constexpr if statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if)? It would [solve](https://godbolt.org/z/KcKssK633) your immediate problem, but I'd consider a complete refactor of the code, getting rid of the union.

Comment: @m.a.g At eruntime is too late.

Comment: @Bob__ I see. I am not too familiar with constexpr if statements. I'll take your advice and go for a refactor

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm not familiar with how to make that check at compile time

Comment: Are you still getting "missing subscript" with the current example? When I tried compiling it, I only got errors corresponding roughly to your "zero-sized array in struct/union" warning. Was there more to that warning? Such as a place in the code where it occurs? A mention of which template is being instantiated? I think clang gives a clearer error message than what you're getting: `error: 'm' declared as an array with a negative size` `note: in instantiation of member class 'Matrix<int, -1, -1>::(anonymous union at prog.cc:9:5)'`. I would highlight the `-1` in `Matrix<int, -1, -1>`...

Comment: Related, but dealing with function templates: [invalid instantiation of template by compiler giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67816795)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Compile time recursion and conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8759872)